# What is the correct order and setup of AC coupling capacitor and line driver?

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors, audio, basic, decoupling-capacitor

When I use an AC coupling cap along with a balance line driver, what is the correct setup? What happens when I omit the resistor in the following schematics? Is it neccessary?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQRQB6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I know the way of calculating the filter cut-off point and resistor values, just wondering what happens when I leave the resistor out?

Comment: Andy answered it, but in case it's still not clear to you, if you leave out R1, it's as if you have a 10k resistor to ground. This is [provided internally](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/196680/how-to-hard-bypass-the-input-of-a-line-driver-with-a-switch/196711?noredirect=1#comment410588_196711) by the drv134.

Comment: Right, I see now that this is a duplicate question although I asked for totally separate reasons. Thanks a lot guys!